# simple PowerShell Select-String Pattern

Tags: powershell

Why doesn't the PowerShell script

```
Get-NetRoute | Select-String -Pattern "255"
Get-NetRoute | Select-String -Pattern 255
Get-NetRoute | Select-String -Pattern '255'
Get-NetRoute | Select-String -Pattern '.*255.*'
```

give any result? Whats wrong with the Pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Select-String` cmdlet is designed to work on string objects. The output of a `Get-NetRoute` cmdlet is an array.

[image]

For your code to work, you would have to convert it to a `string` object like this.

```
(Get-NetRoute | out-string).split("`n") | Select-String -Pattern "255"
```

But I doubt it would be very helpful if you intend to use the results down the lane.

What you really need is `Where-object`.

`Get-NetRoute | Where-Object {$_.DestinationPrefix -like "*255*"}`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`Select-String` will interpret `Get-NetRoute` as a single string (the output is a single object), so you need to split it up using the `-Stream` switch. Note that `ipconfig | select-string` would *not* have the same problem as it is a DOS command and so by default PowerShell will split it per line, but for PowerShell commands you need to do this when you want to do line by line interrogation since the pipeline is passing a single object, so you are doing it right to use Select-String, but just have to understand *how* it interprets input from the pipeline and then it'll work fine:

```
Get-NetRoute | Out-String -Stream | Select-String -Pattern "255"
```